# Error on defining arrays in class

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am trying to make a class that will read a text file of names into an array, then return that array to the main class. However I am having an error when attempting to define the arrays.

```
public class Test{
String[] foo;
String[] zoo;
String[] yoo;
}
```

I get an error on String[] yoo

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this 
token
```

I really have no clue what is going on, can anyone help?

Edit - Actual section of code

```
    String[] swords;
    String[] prefix;
    String[] suffix;
    String[] rarity;
    String[] colors = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"};
    String[] bows = new String[3];
    String[] enchantments = {"Frost","Igniton","Projection","Explosion","Enhance Jump","Enhance Speed","Resist Flames","Invisibility"};
    rarity = new String[1000];
    swords = new String[1000];
    bows = new String[1000];
    prefix = new String[1000];
    suffix = new String[1000];
```

Comment: There is no error in your class code. Can you share the complete code

Comment: there is no error...was compiled successfully in mine

Comment: Ok, i'll add actual code

Comment: what is issuing this error?  your compiler?  your ide?  in which case, can you say which version.

Comment: post full code for good responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not initialize like this in outside the constructors or methods

Wrong:

```
public Test{
 String[] rarity;
 String[] swords;
 rarity = new String[1000]; 
 swords = new String[1000];
}
```

You can do this

```
public Test{
      String[] rarity = new String[1000]; 
      String[] swords = new String[1000];
    }
```

if the variables are static you can use `static` block

```
public Test{
   private static int x;
   static{
          x=2;
   }

}
```

Use constructor instead to initialize:

```
 public Test{
    String[] swords;
    String[] prefix;
    String[] suffix;
    String[] rarity;
    String[] colors = {"2","3","4","5","6","7","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"};
    String[] bows = new String[3];
    String[] enchantments = {"Frost","Igniton","Projection","Explosion","Enhance Jump","Enhance Speed","Resist Flames","Invisibility"};
  public Test(){
    rarity = new String[1000];
    swords = new String[1000];
    bows = new String[1000];
    prefix = new String[1000];
    suffix = new String[1000];
  }
}
```

That's all

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to java and am just trying to get a footing in things.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign values to fields outside of the field declaration or a block (or constructor). So this line

```
rarity = new String[1000];
```

(and the other similar ones) should be in the constructor, or the declaration should also initialize the field:

```
String[] rarity = new String[1000];
```

Answer (score 1):

unless you post all of your code it is not possible to be sure the answer is correct.

but I guess you have this:

```
rarity = new String[1000];
swords = new String[1000];
bows = new String[1000];
prefix = new String[1000];
suffix = new String[1000];
```

outside a method. that is not possible in Java.

do like this instead:

```
String[] rarity = new String[1000];
```

or init the field inside a method/constructor

Comment: After doing that there is still an error on line 7, can you not define the contents of an array outside a method?

Comment: please post at least the first 20 lines of your class, I think you have something on line 7 that is not in line with how Java works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should make them `public` or `private`(unless you really need it to be package-private).

An array is created like this:
`Type[] variableName = new Type[length];`

`length` is the size of the array, for example `String[] test = new String[5]` can contain 5 strings. To set them use `test[i] = someString;` where `i` is the index(starting at 0 and ending at length - 1).

You can also make an ArrayList if you do not want your array to be limited, but that uses a bit more memory.

`ArrayList<Type> variableName = new ArrayList<>();`

For example:
`ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<>();`

To add to it use `test.add(someString)` and to get: `arrayList.get(i)` where `i` is the index.

A disadvantage of `ArrayList` is that primitive types(`int`, `byte`, `boolean`, ...) cannot be used. You'll need to use `Integer`, `Byte`, `Boolean`, ...

If you have an `ArrayList<Integer>`, you could `intArrayList.add(5)` because autoboxing transforms 5 into `new Integer(5)`.

Comment: Making them public would be much worse than leaving them package private.